# Unable to deploy portlet in Liferay 7

Tags: java, gradle, liferay-7

I can not deploy portlet in my project in Liferay.

My gradle file looks like this:

```
#Thu Aug 18 11:52:36 CDT 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.0-bin.zip
```

Firstly, I had an error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111 contains a valid JDK installation.
```

I added this line to gradle file

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_111
```

Now, I have this error:

```
Gradle User Home: C:\Users\Piotr\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 3.0
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: deploy

:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_131 contains a valid JDK installation.
```

Any ideas what should I do to deploy this portlet correctly?

Comment: How did you create your project? Do you use the Liferay workspace?

Comment: Yes, I used LF workspace

Answer (score 0):

From Error Its looks like your Java Home path is wrong.

It should be

```
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
```

If you are deploying from IDE than you can change it from 
Window --> Preferences-->Java-->Installed JREs

```
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 2.14.1
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Gradle Tasks: deploy
```

Comment: I've switched it. Still the same error. That's the problem - even if jdk is set it still don't want to start.